# What is the relation between "block-level box", "block container box" and "block box" in CSS?

Tags: css

I am having hard time to understand these concepts. I am learning from MDN [Visual formatting model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model) as well as from specs [enter link description here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes)
There are so much terms thrown around that I can't even connect them into one stable mental model.
For example on MDN page it says:

> A block-level box may also be a block container box. A block container
>   box is a box that contains only other block-level boxes, or creates an
>   inline formatting context, thus containing only inline boxes.

Then it says:

> It is important to note that the notions of a block-level box and
>   block container box are disjointed. The first, describes how the box
>   behaves with its parents and sibling. The second, how it interacts
>   with its descendants. Some block-level boxes, like tables, aren't
>   block container boxes. Reciprocally, some block container boxes, like
>   non-replaced inline blocks and non-replaced table cells, aren't
>   block-level boxes.
>
> Block-level boxes that also are block container boxes are called block
>   boxes.

Is there some way to explain this so that I get at least some anchor point from where I can expand and include other concepts?

Comment: ^ the duplicate should explain this well, let me know if it's not the case ... basically you have the inside world and the outside world

Comment: Thanks, I looked that but now I have another related question if you can help me out here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56186202/what-is-the-difference-between-containing-block-and-block-container-box-in-c